# Copper standard used for PCB manufacturing

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design, copper

Could someone help me with information associated to the type of copper standard which is used for PCBs (single layer & multiple layers)? And if possible share datasheets if available.

Thank you very much in advance for your reply.
Shubham

Comment: What exactly do you want to know about? the coppe layer thickness?

Comment: You'll probably be able to find this at [IPC](http://www.ipc.org/ContentPage.aspx?pageid=Standards)

Comment: Two useful facts about copper foil: the thermal resistance of standard foil is 70 degreesCentgrade per watt per square. What does "per square" mean? Take a square of foil ---- 1 ounce per foot^2 is the default foil ---- and inject heat on one edge, while on the opposite edge act to remove that heat. You will measure 70 degreeC temperature between those 2 edges. ---- and the electrical resistance will be, if measured with Kelvin connections, 500 microOhms per square of foil, the default 35 micron, 1.4 mil thick copper foil

Answer (score 0):

The wikipedia page on [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPC_(electronics)) lists IPC-4562 Metal Foil for Printed Wiring Applications, you can see from the [table of contents](http://www.ipc.org/TOC/IPC-4562A.pdf) if that provides the information you need.